# Spring boot - application.properties: ERROR to get the Cassandra's data: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I'm trying to get the Cassandra's data from application.properties, but it was returning null when I try to connect with the Cassandra's DB.

**ERROR:**

> java.lang.NullPointerException: null value for
> spark.cassandra.connection.host   at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:91)
> ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]    at
> org.apache.spark.SparkConf.set(SparkConf.scala:83)
> ~[spark-core_2.12-3.1.1.jar:3.1.1]

**aplication.properties:**

```
spring.data.cassandra.cluster= myApp
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points= 127.0.0.1
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name= myappkeyspace
spring.data.cassandra.port= 9042
```

**CassandraConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}")
    private String contactPoints;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.port}")
    private int port;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
    private String keySpace;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.basePackages}")
    private String basePackages;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.data.cassandra.password}")
    private String password;

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return keySpace;
    }

    public CassandraConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected String getContactPoints() {
        return contactPoints;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return SchemaAction.CREATE_IF_NOT_EXISTS;
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getEntityBasePackages() {
        return new String[] { basePackages };
    }

    public String getKeySpace() {
        return keySpace;
    }

    public void setKeySpace(String keySpace) {
        this.keySpace = keySpace;
    }

    public String getBasePackages() {
        return basePackages;
    }

    public void setBasePackages(String basePackages) {
        this.basePackages = basePackages;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void setContactPoints(String contactPoints) {
        this.contactPoints = contactPoints;
    }

    public void setPort(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    @Bean
    public CassandraConfig cluster() {
        CassandraConfig cluster = new CassandraConfig();
        cluster.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        cluster.setPort(port);
        cluster.setUsername(username);
        cluster.setPassword(password);
        return cluster;
    }
```

**DataSourceCassandraConfig**

```
public SparkSession getSession() {
        CassandraConfig cassandraConfig = new CassandraConfig();
        cassandraConfig = cassandraConfig.cluster();
    
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("SparkCassandraApp")
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.host", cassandraConfig.getContactPoints())
                .config("spark.cassandra.connection.port", cassandraConfig.getPort()).config("spark.cassandra.auth.username", cassandraConfig.getUserName())
                .config("spark.cassandra.auth.password", cassandraConfig.getPassword()).master("local[2]").getOrCreate();
        return spark;
}
```

**SpringApplication**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = { "br.com.myapp.*" })
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "br.com.myapp.*" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"br.com.myapp.*"})
public class App extends SpringBootServletInitializer 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

The eclipse's debug show me the null value when I call the cassandraConfig.cluster() in DataSourceCassandraConfig.
Obs.: I tested using @Autowired in the DataSourceCassandraConfig's class.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line of code in the DataSourceCassandraConfig.

```
CassandraConfig cassandraConfig = new CassandraConfig();
```

The above line constructs via the constructor a new instance of CassandraConfig. It does not use the one autowired in the spring context. Replace it with something like this:

**EDIT**

```
@Autowired
CassandraConfig cassandraConfig;

public SparkSession getSession() {
        cassandraConfig = cassandraConfig.cluster();
```

Or better yet, use constructor injection autowiring:

```
private final CassandraConfig inCassandraConfig;

DataSourceCassandraConfig(CassandraConfig inCassandraConfig){
    cassandraConfig = inCassandraConfig;
}

public SparkSession getSession() {
    cassandraConfig = cassandraConfig.cluster()
```

One additional thing to look at is the ComponentScan, to make sure the CassandraConfig and the DataSourceCassandraConfig are within package br.com.myapp.* (or include the package names so I can see them).

A good way to make sure all the spring classes are component scanned is to move all you classes in a package below the class with the @SpringBootApplication annotation (class App in your case). Also, check to see if the @Value annotations are auto wiring or not, maybe even commenting out code to prevent constructors from throwing exceptions. If they are getting not getting populated it's a wiring problem and the class may not being scanned.

Comment: I tried the both examples and it returned null. I updated the question with debug's print.

Comment: spring.data.cassandra.contact-points= 127.0.0.1.  # looks to me like there is an extra space after 127.0.0.1. Would you please remove that and make it: 

spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=127.0.0.1

Comment: I think is not this issue, because the contact-points came when it load the application in the first time. I need to get the spring boot context. There isn't example in the spring documentation using a application.properties. I know my doubt is the beginner, but I can not see. I tested your suggestion and the error persist.

Comment: I found the error.  The problem is that I was creating a new DataSourceCassandraConfig's  instance when I call the sesson's method. It deleted the spring context. I edited your anwser to correct one part of your code to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that when creating the CassandraConfig bean it still hasn't loaded the value of contactPoints. The @Values that you are using will be loaded always after creating the beans.

I think the best you can do here is to create a constructor that receives the values you need like this

```
public CassandraConfig (@Value("${spring.data.cassandra.contact-points}") String contactPoints) {
...whatever code...
this.contactPoints = contactPoints;
...whatever code...
}
```

In this case, the contactPoints will be loaded when creating the bean.

Comment: I tryed this constructor method, but the problem is to load this value after the application is started. It is in the context spring boot.